# Why is the alpha value set by the authors of the paper and not me, the reader?

Tags: p-value

Lets say I read a paper, I think that the data collection method and the measurement practice will introduce noisy data. The sample is small and the underlying hypothesis is somewhat grandios. Something like the existence of ghosts or an octupus that predicts the outcome of some soccer game.

Lets furthermore claim, that the authors proposes a nominal alpha level of 0.2 to claim significance. I would be highly skeptical of any "significant" result. I would also be skeptical of significant results below a typical alpha of 0.05.

This makes me wonder. Why should I care about any alpha the author has set? 
Why is it not common practice to simply report the p values and let every reader set his own threshold at which he would reject the null?

Is it just a matter of convention and I am free to set any alpha I want as a reader? or am I missing something?

Comment: Of course as a reader you can decide to set any alpha you want... there is nothing that would forbid you from doing so, however it is also useful for a profession to have some general agreed standard- in physics for example six sigma in social sciences 0.05. All these standards are ultimately arbitrary but that does not mean they are completely useless. However, going back to your question you can always pick your own alpha. You can have your own interpretation of results as well and you don’t need to follow the authors preferred one...

Comment: I just thought about the following situation: Lets say we both read the same paper and you read it with an alpha of 0.01 in mind, while I read it with an alpha of 0.30 in mind. I think that the evidence is compelling. But you do not. Wouldn't This lead to a discussion that wrongly treats the p-value as a strengh of evidence for the hypothesis?

Comment: it would, that’s why usually scientists don’t make up their mind even if the results are highly significant until replication studies confirm the result or unless the study fits within the existing body of evidence.

Comment: (Well they ought to, but given the replication crises in sevaral scientific domains I think they do not, or can not (as in pressing issues such as Covid 19) but this might be another discussion). Replicability is an important benchmark, but I do not see how important a discussion about replication and compatibility is for the different alpha-level- discussion. What would your answer be, if I modified the scenario by stating, that the study was replicated 400 times with p values between 0.011 and 0.29? A "every reader is free to pick his alpha"-approach would treat it as a strength of evidence.

Comment: you as an individual can always make your own rules how to interpret science. There also already are meta studies that study significance across different studies.

Comment: I can, but that does not mean that the rule is valid. Many researcher interpret a nonsignificant as evidence for the null. which is clearly wrong. I am not sure what your connection between a meta-analysis and my question is...